# Real time validation messages wrong

Tags: javascript, real-time

Hi guys i have a problem with my code

my code is showing message for password input instead of email input message, while im typing in email input

can u help me?

```js
 
    var emInpVal = document.getElementById('emIn');
    var psInpVal = document.getElementById('psIn');      
    var msg = ""; 
        
    function realTime(){
        var loginBtn = document.getElementById('login');
    
        if(emInpVal.value.length <= 5){   
            msg = "Adres e-mail zbyt krótki.";
            loginBtn.disabled = true;
            loginBtn.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        } 
        else if(emInpVal.value.length > 5) {
            msg = "";
            loginBtn.disabled = false;
            loginBtn.style.backgroundColor = '#157e79';
        }
    
        if(psInpVal.value.length <= 6){
            msg = "Hasło musi mieć conajmniej 6 znaków"; 
            loginBtn.disabled = true;
            loginBtn.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }    
        else if(psInpVal.value.length > 6){
            msg = "";
            loginBtn.disabled = false;
            loginBtn.style.backgroundColor = '#157e79';
        }    
            
        document.getElementById('span').innerHTML = msg;
    };
```

```html
  <div id="wrap"> 
        <div class="frame">
          <h1>Login here</h1>
          <h3>You have account already? Click sign in</h3>    
        <form id="forma">        
          <input type="email" id="emIn" name="emailInput" placeholder="Email adress" onkeyup="realTime(this)" required>          
          <input type="password" id="psIn" name="passwordInput" placeholder="Password" onkeyup="realTime(this)" required>    
          <input type="submit" name="signin" id="signIn" value="Sign in">  
          <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login">
          <div class="bottomLink">
          <h1>Forget <a href="#">password</a>?</h1>
          <span id="span"></span>
          </div> 
        </form>
      </div>
```

can't find resolve of problem, even if i put this. to element it's not showing the message

Comment: You "should" be placing your variables **in** the function -- since they are used in that *scope*

Comment: @Zak well it's not changing anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because all the validator will run whenever you fire the `keyUp`, To selectively run a particular validator, I have added an extra check with the `id` of the element which is triggering the `realTime()` function of yours.

```js
var emInpVal = document.getElementById('emIn');
var psInpVal = document.getElementById('psIn');      
var msg = ""; 

function realTime(elem){

    var loginBtn = document.getElementById('login');

    if(elem.id == 'emIn' && emInpVal.value.length <= 5){   
        msg = "Adres e-mail zbyt krótki.";
        loginBtn.disabled = true;
        loginBtn.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } 
    else if(elem.id == 'emIn' && emInpVal.value.length > 5) {
        msg = "";
        loginBtn.disabled = false;
        loginBtn.style.backgroundColor = '#157e79';
    }

    if(elem.id == 'psIn' && psInpVal.value.length <= 6){
        msg = "password should be greater than or equal to 6"; 
        loginBtn.disabled = true;
        loginBtn.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }    
    else if(elem.id == 'psIn' && psInpVal.value.length > 6){
        msg = "";
        loginBtn.disabled = false;
        loginBtn.style.backgroundColor = '#157e79';
    }    

    document.getElementById('span').innerHTML = msg;
};
```

```html
<div id="wrap"> 
    <div class="frame">
      <h1>Login here</h1>
      <h3>You have account already? Click sign in</h3>    
    <form id="forma">        
      <input type="email" id="emIn" name="emailInput" placeholder="Email adress" onkeyup="realTime(this)" required>          
      <input type="password" id="psIn" name="passwordInput" placeholder="Password" onkeyup="realTime(this)" required>    
      <input type="submit" name="signin" id="signIn" value="Sign in">  
      <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login">
      <div class="bottomLink">
      <h1>Forget <a href="#">password</a>?</h1>
      <span id="span"></span>
      </div> 
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: In this code, the message isn't even showing when i'm typing in first input

Answer (score 2):

The first condition is doing right however the problem is that the second condition is executing just after the first condition even if the first condition meets the clause which means it is replacing the error message of the first condition. Below is the correct code.

```
    function realTime() {

        var emInpVal = document.getElementById('emIn');
        var psInpVal = document.getElementById('psIn');
        var msg = "";

        var loginBtn = document.getElementById('login');

        if (emInpVal.value.length <= 5) {
            loginBtn.disabled = true;
            loginBtn.style.backgroundColor = "red";

            document.getElementById('span').innerHTML = "Adres e-mail zbyt krótki.";

            return;
        } else if (psInpVal.value.length <= 6) {
            loginBtn.disabled = true;
            loginBtn.style.backgroundColor = "red";

            document.getElementById('span').innerHTML = "Hasło musi mieć conajmniej 6 znaków";

            return;
        } else {
            msg = "";
            loginBtn.disabled = false;
            loginBtn.style.backgroundColor = '#157e79';

            document.getElementById('span').innerHTML = "";
        }
    };
```

Comment: thank You for a quick response :) and You made less code :)

Comment: @wilk85: The problem with this solution could be when you start typing the password first, you will get messages for email. If that's not the case, it's perfectly fine..

Comment: You are right however I have just corrected @wilk85 code. This code in fact can be refactored and improved.

Comment: i was wondering with using return state, because it;s finishing code. And i saw that in your code :)

Comment: Please go ahead and remove the return statement because the other conditions wouldn’t anyway execute if one is matched.

Comment: In this code, when i'm typing email address it's fine till i hit 6th character, then it's showing password message, so it's not working properly

Answer (score 0):

Ok i've found answer for that problem, 
thank You guys for helping
second if needs add of &&

Now i have another problem when i fill both inputs, and disabled property turns false so every conditions are done, i want to delete value of first input (email) and nothing happens now, conditions aren't changing back to disabled = true, and message of short email value not showing..

```
function realTime(){
    var emInpVal = document.getElementById('emIn');
    var psInpVal = document.getElementById('psIn');      
    var msg = ""; 
    var loginBtn = document.getElementById('login');

    if(emInpVal.value.length <= 5){   
        msg = "Adres e-mail zbyt krótki.";
        loginBtn.disabled = true;
        loginBtn.style.backgroundColor = "red";  
    }

    else if(emInpVal.value.length > 5){
        msg = "";
        loginBtn.disabled = false;
        loginBtn.style.backgroundColor = "#157e79";
    }

    if(psInpVal.value.length > 0 && psInpVal.value.length <= 6){
        msg = "Hasło jest za krótkie"
        loginBtn.disabled = true;
        loginBtn.style.backgroundColor = "red";  
    } 

    else if(psInpVal.value.length > 6){
        msg = "";
        loginBtn.disabled = false;
        loginBtn.style.backgroundColor = '#157e79';    
    }       



    document.getElementById('span').innerHTML = msg;
};
```